# Different formulas for matrix transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am a bit confused about how to get a matrix in a new basis.

On the one hand, we always use the multiplication by transformation matrix when we want to receive a matrix in a new basis:

- $A' = CA$, where $A'$ is a matrix in a new basis; $C$ is a transformation matrix; $A$ is a matrix in the standard basis.

However, when we speak about getting the matrix in its eigenbasis, we use the other formula.

- $A = C^{-1}A'C$, where $A$ is a matrix in a standard basis; $A'$ is a matrix in the eigenbasis; $C$ is the transformation matrix.

Why do we have different formulas while doing the same thing (matrix transformations) or do I get something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any transformation of a matrix in a new basis has the form $A=C^{-1}A'C$. This is a consequence of the fact that a matrix represents a linear transformation that is the same in any basis.

So, for a vector $x$, whose components are expressed in the standard basis, we have the transformation $x \rightarrow Ax$.  In the new basis we have $x \rightarrow x'=Cx$ and the new matrix $A'$ acts on $x'$ in such a way that if we return to the standard basis, by menas of  $C^{-1}$,  the result is the same $Ax$.

This means that we must have
$ A x= (C^{-1}A' C )x \quad \forall x $.